# Screen shot of website not working

Tags: website, screenshot

I'm trying to take a screenshot of a website but it captures a blank screen - similar to taking a screenshot of flash, however, the website's built with the **jquery UI**!

Is there a program available that can do this?

I'm on OS X Lion using google chrome. Im currently using browser extensions to take screenshots of webpages - specifically the awesome screenshot extension for chrome

Comment: How are you trying to take the screenshot anyway? What OS are you on? What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Take a high resolution screenshot of a website](http://superuser.com/questions/30858/take-a-high-resolution-screenshot-of-a-website)

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: sorry, should have provided more information. I'm on OS X Lion using google chrome. Im currently using browser extensions to take screenshots of webpages - specifically the awesome screenshot extension for chrome

Comment: Use a different extension/print screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Pixlr Grabber, a firefox addon.
Can save it as an image, copy it to clipboard, upload it on Imm.io

It's ability: Grab the entire page or a piece of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Snipper. It comes bundled with Windows 7 (if you're using that).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure really what you mean in your question, but apart from the standard PrtScn, I have had great success with [Snagit](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html). There is a 30 day trial for testing purposes.